# Vue create “projectName” ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT - fails all the time no matter what - taobao

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I am getting a bit confused about what’s been happening to me recently.

Whenever I want to create a new vue project, it fails with:

```
Vue CLI v4.5.11
✨  Creating project in /home/admin/Documents/dev/my_projects/vThesaurus/thesaurus.
⚙️  Installing CLI plugins. This might take a while...

npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npm.taobao.org/jsonfile failed, reason: Socket timeout

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/admin/.npm/_logs/2021-03-17T06_40_10_793Z-debug.log
ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error --legacy-peer-deps
```

another packages from prev attempts:

```
request to https://registry.npm.taobao.org/core-js-compat failed, reason: Socket timeout
request to https://cdn.npm.taobao.org/micromatch/-/micromatch-4.0.2.tgz failed, reason: Socket timeout
request to https://registry.npm.taobao.org/querystring-es3 failed, reason: Socket timeout
request to https://registry.npm.taobao.org/file-loader failed, reason: Socket timeout
```

… and many more

Log: (last part)

```
4675 timing command:install Completed in 378261ms
4676 verbose type system
4677 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://registry.npm.taobao.org/jsonfile failed, reason: Socket timeout
4677 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/minipass-fetch/lib/index.js:97:14)
4677 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
4677 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:463:9)
4677 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:327:22)
4677 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:100:8)
4677 verbose stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:68:3)
4677 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
4678 verbose cwd /home/admin/Documents/dev/my_projects/vThesaurus/thesaurus
4679 verbose Linux 5.4.0-67-generic
4680 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--loglevel" "error" "--legacy-peer-deps"
4681 verbose node v14.2.0
4682 verbose npm  v7.6.3
4683 error code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
4684 error errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
4685 error request to https://registry.npm.taobao.org/jsonfile failed, reason: Socket timeout
4686 verbose exit 1
the weirdest part is that it always fails on a different package …
```

I tried:

- to remove nodejs and vue, reinstall again but no luck …
- to increase timeout in the `~/.npmrc` but no luck again … (I don’t have slow internet connection - ping 3ms, d: 96Mbps, u: 9.6Mbps)
- nothing I found on the internet seems to be working …
- changing IPs (nordvpn) to reach to diff servers (CDN) but no luck
- vue2 and vue3 ends up with the same failure (random package failure all the time)
- manually accessing the failed package - guess what, it works great
- tried to add `{ "useTaobaoRegistry": false }` in the `~/.vimrc` … no luck again
- tried different network provider... no luck :(

nothing seems to be working …

---

**npm -v**
7.6.3

**vue --version**
@vue/cli 4.5.11

**OS:** Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 64bit

**Gnome version:** 3.36.8

what am I missing?

Comment: Did you tried to upgrade it ? `yarn global upgrade --latest @vue/cli` or `npm update -g @vue/cli` (depending on the one you're using). Also, did you checked the warning at the top of this page ? https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html Lastly, what is the command that you run exactly when using the CLI ?

Comment: yes I have the lastest one .. I even tried to uninstall everything and install again .. didn't work :( to create a project, I use regular `vue create projectname`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you do have issues with taobao in particular. From this [github thread](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/6003#issuecomment-716158880), we may try to not use it anymore.

For that, you can go to your `~/.vuerc` and set `"useTaobaoRegistry": false`.

---

`yarn config get registry` is giving me `https://registry.yarnpkg.com`.

Comment: weird thing is, that when I keep trying creating the project (click overwrite .... when re-executing the project creation) I will get there eventually after some tries.. I tried creating a dummy project now  (without disabling the taobao as you suggested) and it worked ok ... dunno what happened... if it keeps on failing, I will try the suggestion of yours ... so far, it seems like the only solution ... anyway, any idea what happened to taobao and why it's suggested to disable??

funny point, I tried that but put that in vimrc instead vuerc :D